# Next.js api endpoint is not loading req.query values and delivers empty instead, loads twice consecutively

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an endpoint that receives data from the frontend via `req.query`, but it oddly does not load the values within the object.

This is my code for the endpoint:

```js
const getAccountsSummary = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) => {
  const { accountList } = req.query;
  console.log('[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] req.query', req.query);

  console.log('[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] accountList', accountList);
  const { user } = req.headers;

  if (accountList === undefined) {
    console.log(
      '[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] accountList === undefined',
      accountList,
      accountList === undefined
    );
    return res.status(400).json({
      message:
        "Error loading account summary Error: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.",
    });
  }

  console.log('[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] accountList 2', accountList);
  if (!accountList) {
    console.log(
      '[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] !accountList',
      accountList,
      !accountList
    );
    return res.status(404).json({
      message:
        "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI.",
    });
  }

  const accountArray = (accountList as string).split(',');

  const accountExists = accountArray.every((item) => {
    return dbAccounts[user as keyof TDbAccounts].summary.find(
      (account) => account.account === parseInt(item)
    );
  });

  if (!accountExists) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      message: "Account doesn't exist.",
    });
  }

  const dbAccountSummary = dbAccounts[user as keyof TDbAccounts].summary;

  const listContents = accountArray.map((item) => {
    return {
      account: parseInt(item),
      name: dbAccountSummary.find(
        (account) => account.account === parseInt(item)
      )?.name,
      currency: dbAccountSummary.find(
        (account) => account.account === parseInt(item)
      )?.currency,
      position: dbAccountSummary.find(
        (account) => account.account === parseInt(item)
      )?.position,
    };
  });

  return res.status(200).json({
    list: listContents,
  });
};
```

The `console.log()` outputs the following:

```
[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] req.query { accountList: '' }
[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] accountList
[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] accountList 2
[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] !accountList  true
[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] req.query { accountList: '1011018,1011019' }
[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] accountList 1011018,1011019
[DEBUG][getAccountsSummary] accountList 2 1011018,1011019
```

As you can see, upon a single request sent to the API, the `req.query` has the `accountList` property but is `undefined`. However, the data endpoint seems to run again without requiring to have received an additional request, and this time the `accountList` property seems to have assigned the value that was expected.

This is a problem for me because the frontend receives the first run without the required data and then receives the second run, which is the one that has the data. However, there is much code in place in the frontend meant to handle errors such as what is sent in the first response... and yet, in the seond response it all sorts out but the frontend already warned the user of existing errors.

What is happening and how can I make the API work on the first time, without having it run twice?

JIC these are the dependencies in my package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
}
```

Comment: Can you share code where you are calling `getAccountsSummary` API?